# Flutter app ApplePayButton widget retunes the error: failed to present payment controller

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, applepay

To test the `ApplePayButton` widget, I tried creating a new sample Flutter project using `flutter create .` And in the Hello world screen, I added one thing only which is `ApplePayButton` widget from `pay` dependency because my original project was returning a weird error which is `platformexception(paymenterror, failed to present payment controller, null, null)` from the `onError` property, but I ended up getting the same error in the new hello world project so there is hardly any context. Here is the widget I used and the configuration:

```
            ApplePayButton(
              onPaymentResult: (result) => greenToast(result.toString()),
              paymentItems: [
                PaymentItem(
                  amount: "111.01",
                  label: "test",
                ),
              ],
              onError: (error) => redToast(error.toString()),
              paymentConfiguration: PaymentConfiguration.fromJsonString('''
                {
                "provider": "apple_pay",
                "data": {
                  "merchantIdentifier": "merchant.xxx.xxx",
                  "displayName": "app_name",
                  "merchantCapabilities": ["3DS", "debit", "credit"],
                  "supportedNetworks": ["amex", "visa", "mada", "masterCard"],
                  "countryCode": "SA",
                  "currencyCode": "SAR"
                  }
                }
                '''),
            ),
```

Some notes about my setup and things I tried:

- My original app's primary language is Arabic
- I tried restarting the MacOS and XCode for possible cache issues
- In the MacOS, I compile the Runner using the command: `flutter ios --release --no-tree-shake-icons`
- Then updated Flutter to fix the issue of shaking icons and compiled the app using `flutter ios --release`
- the app name was containing arabic characters along with the character '|', but I fixed that and made all the naming in only English, specially in the new Flutter sample project
- the Apple Pay button is working fine on the iOS simulator on MacOS
- I tried 2 different physical iPhones but got the same error
- The iPhones I tested have been used to buy through Apple Pay before
- Merchant ID is setup with an active `Apple Pay Payment Processing Certificate`
- The Class `PlatformException` from Flutter didn't return any more information as far as I know except: `platformexception(paymenterror, failed to present payment controller, null, null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't notice that I needed to check the checkbox here:

[image]